# Error building Android Library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-library

I am getting this error when building the library: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`

This is what I get when I get java versions on my Mac:

```
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

The project is open source here: https://github.com/NickM-27/LinkPreview

I have tried cleaning as well as clearing and re-downloading from git to no avail

Please let me know what other information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have multiple Java versions installed on your machine? `kapt` has a bug which does not pickup the correct Java version defined as default in `compileOptions {}` block in Gradle.

Kapt is most likely using recent version of Java which split Jaxb class into separate module since Java version 9.

[How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Until the Kapt bug (I don't have a link) is fixed, uninstall unneeded Java versions or force `kapt` to pickup the correct version by adding this:

```
kapt {      
    javacOptions {
         option("-source", "8")
         option("-target", "8")
    }
```

Reference: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1449

Comment: Yep that's it, unfortunately I need the newer java version so this code should do the trick. Thanks!